# Windows 2008 64-bit, .NET 3.5 Framework still has memory limit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, out-of-memory

On a .NET 3.5 Framework, 64-bit Windows 2008 Server system, we are bumping into a 2GB memory limit.  We do not have any single object that is over 2GB (largest object is 700 MB).  The program hits close to 1.5GB, starts becoming unstable, and eventually crashes with the 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error.

We're at a bit of a loss since the 64-bit system should have the 8TB limit and no single object is hitting close to 2GB.  Any thoughts on what could be causing the limitation?  If someone with a Win2008 Server (64-bit) upgrades to .NET 3.5 Framework, are they still limited by the 4GB found in 3.0 (installed with Win2008)?  If so, how do I get around this?

Comment: What is your application type and how do you deploy it? (win, iis, etc)

Comment: And is your code compiled to target either AnyCpu or x64?

Comment: Change the EXE project's Platform target setting from x86 to AnyCPU.

Comment: Can you verify that it is running in 64-bit mode by outputting the value of Environment.Is64BitProcess?  Also, do you get different results when you target x64?

Comment: Platform is AnyCPU, target is x86

Comment: x86 as the target is your problem. It has to be AnyCPU as well.

Comment: I don't think it could be the AnyCPU/x86 because we can compile it locally, run it, and it will use up to 10GB of memory on our local machines (Windows 7, 64-bit, 3.5 Framework).  However, when we put the software on other machines as described in the question it does not work.

Comment: @pcrary - You need to compile it to target x64.  Otherwise change it to target AnyCPU, THIS IS THE PROBLEM, it crystal clear you have not tried it.

Comment: I am not targeting x64 platforms.  Why would I want to compile it for that if it would create a product that I don't want?